# Django Rest Framework - How to route to a function view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using `Django` with `Django Rest Framework`.

```
Django==2.0.2
djangorestframework==3.7.7
```

I am trying to route to a `function view`.

My current setup looks like this:

```
- project
    - project
        - urls
    - app
        - urls
        - views
```

In `project/urls`, I reference the `app's` urls like this:

`url(r'^app_api/', include('app_api.urls', namespace='app_api'))`

In `app/urls`, I route to the views like this:

```
router.register(r'', views.app_api, base_name="app_api")
url(r'', include(router.urls)),
```

In `app/views` I have defined a function called `app_api` and decorated it with `api_view`.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def app_api(request):
```

If I run the server and `curl http://localhost:8080/app_api/` for example, I get a response with status 200 and a empty JSON.

`"GET /app_api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2`
`{}`

I do not understand why this is happening. If I use a class based viewset, it works, but not with a function view.

What is the correct way of routing to a function view when using `Django Rest Framework`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using a router here. Those are for viewsets: the router generates all URL endpoints for the viewset. You have a single view; it makes no difference if it's a class or function, you need to declare an explicit endpoint for it just like in plain Django.

Comment: I see. Yes, declaring a explicit route worked. I assumed using a router was good practice. This explains why my other approach worked. Thanks!