# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions' in function view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-urls, django-rest-viewsets

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def poll(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        question = Question.objects.all()
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(question, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        data = JsonParser.parse(request.POST)
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

**api_urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'poll', views.poll, basename='poll')

urlpatterns = [
    path('poll/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**error**

```
 File "C:\Users\azhar\.virtualenvs\Django_and_Rest-YRrszWnq\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 152, in get_routes
    extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

> many solution available for how to use get_extra_actions in class View but I want to use it in poll function please help me out

Comment: possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736006/django-rest-framework-how-to-route-to-a-function-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`poll` is a [function based `view`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views), not a [`viewset`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/). So you can't register it to a router. You can directly use it in the view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('poll/', views.poll),
]
```